# Google Custom Audience/Similar Audience API

Tags: google-ads-api, facebook-custom-audience

How can a CRM data be sent to Google Ads via API as a custom audience just like Facebook Custom Audience?
Is there any sample APIs that I can refer to build one.

What i see so far is below on google Ads, https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/audience-types/customer-match

But what we looking for is something like this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/custom-audiences/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the audience data (which can't have any PII) to a custom audience in Google ads. It's a little bit hacky as there's no official 3rd party integrations. We use Adobe Analytics data and audiences from AAM for example, and map them to custom audiences using the process outlined here:

https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/audience-manager/user-guide/implementation-integration-guides/integrating-third-party/rlsa-integration.html

Comment: So there is no 3rd integrations like Facebook do? we unfortunately need a direct connector rather going via other tools.